Задание через Task Sheduler в WinServer 2016 запускается три раза
Делаю задание через таск менеджер. Прописываю тригер - запускать мою программу через час. Она через час запускается. Но три раза подряд.
Если в закладке Settings, в If the task fails, restart task every: поставить галочку и задать 1 минуту и 1 раз, запустится 1 раз через минуту. Если снять галочку, опять три раза.
От того, что возвращает моя программа, ничего не зависит. Пытался возвращать 0, пытался возвращать другие значения, ничего не меняется.
Может кто-то сталкивался и знает как это лечится?
